# Identify last active Linux bash process

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, process, pid

On Linux (e.g. RHEL 6) how do I on a given host identify the pid that last did some computation ? More precisely: among my 59 bash shells (I love virtual desktops), I would like to identify the terminal where I latest executed a command.

I tried looking in /proc/<pid> for some of my bash terminals to see if there were e.g. a command history file, or virtual file with a usable date stamp. Did not find anything.

Comment: I need more information. Can you tell more about what you understand with "some computation"? Is it the last command launched in a one of your 59 running instances of bash?

Comment: ... or is it the command that finished the last? `pid that last did some computation` ≠ `terminal where I latest executed a command`. There are two points which need clarification: _ **1.** Do you want the *terminal* PID or do you want the *bash* PID? _ **2.** Do you want the bash/terminal where you *started* the most recent command or do you want the bash/terminal where the last *finished* command ran?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `PROMPT_COMMAND` which is executed each time bash displays a prompt, that is, after every command. In the prompt command, write the current PID to a file. When looking for the bash process that finished the latest command, retrieve its PID from that file.

In your `~/.bashrc` add

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $$ > /tmp/last_active_bash_pid'
```

The effect will take place when you restart all your terminals or when your source the file in each terminal (execute `. ~/.bashrc`).

You can test this interactively using `watch -n0.3 cat /tmp/last_active_bash_pid` to show the PID.

Comment: You need probably also to echo the terminal name along to the PID for answering the question, v.gr. with the command `tty`.